# database connecting to java code wont run

Tags: java, database

I was trying to access my database from a java program and created one table to see if it works.
The program compiled perfectly fine, yet the table doesn't appear in the program output. What's wrong?

```
package db_cliinic;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class DB_Cliinic {

public static void main(String[] args) {

 Connection con = null;
        Statement stat = null;
        ResultSet res = null;
        String q = "select * from DB.EMPLOYEE";
        try { 

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost1527/VetClinic", "DB", "123456");
        stat = con.createStatement();
        res = stat.executeQuery(q);

        while (res.next()) {

            char id = (char) res.getCharacterStream("EMP_ID").read();
            String name = res.getString("NAME");
            char phone =(char) res.getCharacterStream("PHONE_NUMBER").read();
            String Edu = res.getString("EDUCATION_LEVEL");
            double sal = res.getDouble("SALARY");
            String role = res.getString("ROLE");
            char sex = (char) res.getCharacterStream("SEX").read();
            String addr = res.getString("ADDRESS");
            char crn = (char) res.getCharacterStream("ECRN").read();
            char super_id = (char) res.getCharacterStream("SUPER_ID").read();



            System.out.println("  "+id+"  "+name+"  "+phone+"  "+Edu+"  "+sal+"  "+role+"  "+sex+"  "+addr+"  "+crn+super_id);

        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e){      
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DB_clinic.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  }  }  }
```

Comment: shouldn't this "jdbc:derby://localhost1527/VetClinic" be "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/VetClinic" with colon ":"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class DB_Cliinic {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stat = null;
        ResultSet res = null;
        String q = "select * from EMPLOYEE";
        try { 

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/VetClinic;");
        stat = con.createStatement();
        res = stat.executeQuery(q);

        while (res.next()) {

            char id = (char) res.getCharacterStream("EMP_ID").read();
            String name = res.getString("NAME");
            char phone =(char) res.getCharacterStream("PHONE_NUMBER").read();
            String Edu = res.getString("EDUCATION_LEVEL");
            /*TODO: uncomment the block below*/ 
            /*double sal = res.getDouble("SALARY");
            String role = res.getString("ROLE");
            char sex = (char) res.getCharacterStream("SEX").read();
            String addr = res.getString("ADDRESS");
            char crn = (char) res.getCharacterStream("ECRN").read();
            char super_id = (char) res.getCharacterStream("SUPER_ID").read();*/



            System.out.println("  "+id+"  "+name+"  "+phone+"  "+Edu);

        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DB_Cliinic.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  }  }  }
```

- Try to add one stage of debugging as I did with: `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` you will see the error.
  The error is caused by a connection problem to the database.
- Correction of the connection problem

Your database name is `VetClinic` and your table is `EMPLOYEE`

- Interactive Derby command to create your database

  `connect 'jdbc:derby:VetClinic;create=true';`
- Create the table and insert data

`create table EMPLOYEE(EMP_ID   char(10) primary key, NAME varchar(50), PHONE_NUMBER char(10), EDUCATION_LEVEL varchar(50), ...)`;

`insert into EMPLOYEE values ('id-1', 'name1', '00001', "Level10"), ('id-2', 'name2', '00002', 'Level11'), ...;`

- At the end make sure you have the correct connection url `jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/VetClinic;`

Before you execute the program start the Derby server, the message must look like

> Please make sure that Apache Derby Network Server started and is ready to accept connections on port 1527

Answer (score 0):

you most likely get a `SQLException` but it's catch block is empty. Try to log it as well and see what it says.

Your connection URL looks suspicious - I assume you meant to say "localhost:1527" rather than "localhost1527"?!